# Formula for Calculating Periodic Fixed Payments with Multiple Rate Changes

Tags: mortgage, calculation, repayment, adjustable-rate-mortgage

I'm trying to figure out how to extend the formula provided by Chris Degnen in this previous question [What is the formula for the monthly payment on an adjustable rate mortgage?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/61639/what-is-the-formula-for-the-monthly-payment-on-an-adjustable-rate-mortgage/88349#88349) to add in a third interest rate, e.g. for an extra 2 years after the 2nd term has run for 5 years.  So the question would be:

Calculating fixed repayments for a £100,000 loan repaid by 7 annual payments. The first 2 years at 3%, the following 3 years at 4% and the final 2 years at 5%.

I would appreciate any help on this - thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Extending the example in the [link](https://money.stackexchange.com/a/61658/11768).

```
d is the periodic payment
p is the loan amount
r1 is the periodic rate for the first m periods
r2 is the periodic rate for the next n periods
r3 is the periodic rate for the next o periods

p = 100000
r1 = 0.03
m = 2
r2 = 0.04
n = 3
r3 = 0.05
o = 2
```

Discounting each payment to net present value:

```
pv1 = d/(1 + r1)
pv2 = d/((1 + r1) (1 + r1))
pv3 = d/((1 + r1) (1 + r1) (1 + r2))
pv4 = d/((1 + r1) (1 + r1) (1 + r2) (1 + r2))
pv5 = d/((1 + r1) (1 + r1) (1 + r2) (1 + r2) (1 + r2))
pv6 = d/((1 + r1) (1 + r1) (1 + r2) (1 + r2) (1 + r2) (1 + r3))
pv7 = d/((1 + r1) (1 + r1) (1 + r2) (1 + r2) (1 + r2) (1 + r3) (1 + r3))

p = pv1 + pv2 + pv3 + pv4 + pv5 + pv6 + pv7
```

> 6.08738 d

So `p = 6.08738 d` therefore `d = 100000/6.08738 = 16427.43`

Expressing the above using summations and formulae:

[image]

```
p = (d - d (1 + r1)^-m)/r1 +

    1/(1 + r1)^m (d - d (1 + r2)^-n)/r2 +

    1/((1 + r1)^m (1 + r2)^n) (d - d (1 + r3)^-o)/r3
```

> 6.08738 d

There is a clear pattern to extend the formula for any number of changes.  Here is the mathematical formula, but it does not simplify:

With

```
z[1] = r1, z[2] = r2, z[3] = r3, etc.
v[1] = m,  v[2] = n,  v[3] = o, etc.
```

[image]

```
f[3]
```

> 6.08738 d

```
∴ d = 100000/6.08738 = 16427.43
```

Returning to the three-rate formula and rearranging for `d`:

```
p = (d - d (1 + r1)^-m)/r1 +
    1/(1 + r1)^m (d - d (1 + r2)^-n)/r2 +
    1/((1 + r1)^m (1 + r2)^n) (d - d (1 + r3)^-o)/r3

∴ d = (p r1 (1 + r1)^m r2 (1 + r2)^n r3 (1 + r3)^o)/
     (-r1 r2 + (1 + r3)^o (r1 (r2 - r3) +
          (1 + r2)^n (r1 + (-1 + (1 + r1)^m) r2) r3))

    = 16427.43
```